# Javascript have to click button twice which is outside the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

Hi I am facing a problem on button click. I have a button outside the form due to some reason. On the click i have to validate the form and proceed to the next tab. But right now I have to click twice the button even if the form is valid. What's the issue right now?
[image: Registration-2]

**script.js**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#step-2-form').submit(function(e)
{
var $as = $(this);
    if($as.valid()){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dgstoneVariable').edatagrid('reload');
return document.getElementById('n.3').click();  
    }
    if(!$as.valid()){   
    }

});

    $('#step-2-form').validate({
        rules: {
        contactname2field: {
                required: true
            },
            jobtitle2field: {
                required: true
            },
            telephone2field: {
                required: true
            },
            email2field: {
                email: true,
                required: true
            },
            cityfield: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In registration.php I have three tab on 2nd tab I have a a structure as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="step-2-form">

</form>

 <form target="upload_target" id="fileupload" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('upload_file/upload_it'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
....
//Here is a code of file upload. If the user browse and uploads the file then have to click continue button once to move onward. But if the user doesnt upload the files then he has to click the button twice to continue to step 3. (ANY IDEA ...???)
<button id="btnupload" style="padding: 4.5px; float:left;margin-top: 30px;border-radius: 0px;" disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></button>
</form>

<button form="step-2-form" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="tab-2-cont">CONTINUE</button>
```

The above button validtes the first form and then proceeds further. I have to place it outside because of the file uploading form.

Comment: if you are placing the button outside the form then change the type to "button" instead of "submit". Since it doesn't makes sense.

Comment: `return document.getElementById('n.3').click();` ? 
where is this element n.3 ? and why are you using native js for this 
`return $('#n.3').click();`

Comment: Where is this element **`n.3`** ?

Comment: @Shanoop it should be $('#n.3').trigger("click"); But dont know it is the answer OP is looking for.

Comment: some problem at here return document.getElementById('n.3').click();

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj Ho yeah.. ma bad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to handle submit event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#step-2-form').submit(function(e) {  
        var $as = $(this);
        if(!$as.valid()){   
            e.preventDefault();
            // Your error Message
        }
    });
});
```

To Associate button with your from you can use `form` attribute of [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

> The form element that the button is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a  element in the same document. If this attribute is not specified, the  element must be a descendant of a form element. This attribute enables you to place  elements anywhere within a document, not just as descendants of their  elements.

So add form attribute. **You don't need your button to be a descendant of a form element**

```
<button form="step-2-form" id="tab-2-cont" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">CONTINUE</button>
```

A good read [**HTML5′s New “form” Attribute**](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/)

Comment: As OP wants to keep the button out of the form how come you suggest to handle submit event?

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj See `form="step-2-form"`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button before downvoting. And I have not suggested OP to move button inside form

Comment: Since he is using the validate plugin, if the form has associated submit button then the validation call will be triggered by clicking upon the button.. That's the reason usually keeping the button outside the form.

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj, You should also go through http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned anything about HTML5 form and dont assume the browser support yourself.

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj, Are you not assuming **That's the reason usually keeping the button outside the form.**. And thats the way forward

Comment: I dont have to submit the form basically I have to move to the step-3. thats why i did a change in the code. its working fine but tell me is it the correct way?

Comment: @BinteHava, As per my understanding this is the correct way forward

Comment: @Saptal ok Thanx :) But can u tell me that why is it so that if i dont use e.preventDefault the and press continue it goes to process 3 and suddenly page refresh and comes to 1st tab. but it works fine if i use e.preventDefault.

Comment: @BinteHava, `e.preventDefault()` cancels the form submit. As per above code it prevents form being submitted if there are validation errors

Answer (score 1):

Use .submit() mehtod to submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tab-2-cont').click(function() {  
        var $as = $('#step-2-form');
        if($as.valid()){   
            $as.submit();
        }
        else
        {
          // alert("Not valid");
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First when you put a submit button inside form. it will trigger submit event. So if you want to validate data before submit. prevent that event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tab-2-cont').click(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        var $as = $('#step-2-form');
        if($as.valid()){   
            $as.submit();
        }
        else
        {
          // error messages
        }    
});
```

Your question is very unclear, Try this move your button inside your form.

Comment: No need to  move submit button inside form since he is explicitly calling .valid() method. common man..

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj I said this because OP is trying some other element `#n.3` to achieve submit. OP can remove other elements and can use only one submit button. And I think that would best practice

Comment: this explanation doesn't related to my comment :)